# Rails 5.1.: destroy records in "has_many: through" association with restriction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have classic `has_many: through` relationship:

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups_users
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups_users
end

class UserGroupsUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_group
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups_users
  has_many :user_groups, through: :user_groups_users
end
```

and in order to destroy `UserGroup` record, I need to destroy appropriate records in `UserGroupsUser`, which both is part of a gem. Otherwise I will get back error that there are Users tied to UserGroups and I cannot destroy particular `UserGroup`.

At the moment in my Controller I have this:

```
  def destroy
    @user_group = UserGroup.find(params[:id])
    UserGroupsUser.where(user_group_id: @user_group).destroy_all
    respond_to do |format|
    if @user_group.destroy
      format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "User group #{@user_group.name} deleted!" }
      format.html { redirect_to user_groups_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.js { flash[:danger] = "User group #{@user_group.name} cannot be deleted because
                                   #{@user_group.users.size} users belong to it" }
    end
    end
  end
```

however when I click Delete button in View, it destroys a record before I accept that in my modal window. **How do I make it do `destroy` action, after accept in view, please?** As I undestand it would require that after accept, it would firs destroy records in `through` models and then `UserGroup`.

My "Delete" action in View is quite regular:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user_group, method: :delete, remote: true, 
data: { confirm: "Do you confirm deleting #{user_group.name}?" }, class: 'btn-danger btn btn-xs' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `has_many :user_groups_users` to `has_many :user_groups_users, :dependent => :destroy`

See more at [Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Edit: You said it was in a gem. Not an issue, still! Find the class, and add this in an initializer (I know, I know, there are better places, but for the sake of moving on from this):

```
Whatever::To::UserGroupThing.class_eval do 
  has_many :user_group_users, :dependent => :destroy 
end
```

But maintenance may not be your friend here if there's some sort of change to the association made down the line by the maintainer.

You could also use a before_destroy hook in user_group.rb

```
before_destroy do 
  UserGroupUser.where(:user_group => self).destroy_all
end
```

Comment: I know this, however I can't do it as `UserGroupsUser` model is in gem. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you. Does that second solution would go into my Controller, right? First one is quite tricky, because as you said - gem's maintainer may change something in the Model.

Comment: Gets thrown into your user_group.rb model.

Comment: Thank you, probably this would work,however I can't modify anything but `User` model. I think I'll do it from different angle. I will allow `current_user` to untie all users from particular user group and then if there is no users in particular group, I'll automatically delete that group. I could even throw warning for `current_user` that it is last user for the group and if there is no user in group, it will be deleted. I don't want to keep any unused items in my DB. In addition this will keep preventing of situation when some user appears to loose any group and basically can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the whole thing, you could just add a `before_destroy` callback to your `UserGroup`. It'll only execute when you run `@user_group.destroy`

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups_users
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups_users

  before_destroy do
    user_groups_users.destroy_all
  end
end
```

Read [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: Since the Model is in gem, I can't modify it. All of my custom modifications have to be done in my Controller. Can I do something similar there, please?

Comment: @matiss which gem?

Comment: It's [Strongbolt](https://github.com/605data/strongbolt) where I'm implementing functionality which allows create custom User Groups for `current_user`.

Comment: Basically at the moment there is this `:dependent => :restrict_with_exception` in the Model and I cannot modify that.